# Software Center won't start after interrupted installation

Tags: 13.10, software-center

I was installing Kingsoft Office using a deb file. During installation the system hung and I was forced to switch off my laptop. Now on restarting I am unable to start the Software Center. I tried so many things but always get this message:

```
E:The package kingsoft-office:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Solved with follwoing command.
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq kingsoft-office:i386

found solution here:http://musaamin.web.id/solved-mengatasi-pesan-error-e-the-package-nama-paket-needs-to-be-reinstalled/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you've solved your own question, please post the solution as an answer rather than a comment, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq kingsoft-office:i386
```

Found solution here: http://musaamin.web.id/solved-mengatasi-pesan-error-e-the-package-nama-paket-needs-to-be-reinstalled/